# Can I add not-for-display comments in plantuml text file?

Tags: plantuml

I like to add some notes/comments in plantuml text file and do not want them to show up in the generated diagram. Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible the comment sign for a plantuml file is the single quote (`'`).

The following:

```
@startuml
' the initial program
Bob -> Alice : hello
@enduml
```

will render as:

[image]